# searchkich search all data how we can increase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I am using [searchkich](http://searchkick.org/) 
it has method to find all the record with like `Model.search('*')` but it only returns 1000 records , can anyone help how I can increase it's size 100 to **all records**

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to change the import batch size for example:

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick batch_size: 5000 # defaults to 1000
end

You won't be able to specify all records however if you know the largest data-set you can try to specify that number as the `limit`

```
Product.search "2% Milk", limit: 5000, offset: 50
```

Unfortunately I believe the max return is the same as Elastic Search (10,000 documents) so that may be your hard ceiling.